# Parallel.ForEach and shared safe collection!

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, concurrency, parallel-processing

I cannot figure out why my following code is not working properly. This is the simplified version of it

```
public class TheClass
{
    protected void SomeMethod(List<string> works)
    {
         ConcurrentBag<MyResult> mySafeCollection= new ConcurrentBag<MyResult>();

         Parallel.ForEach(works, work=>
            { 
                   mySafeCollection.Add(GetResult(work));

            }
    }

    private MyResult GetResult(string work)
    {
        ResultClass result = new ResultClass ();
        result.Id = "some text";
        //Some work here to set result.Value
        return result;
     }
}
```

As seen, I have a class that gets a list of string, works, and then call some local method which does some work and return a result object. I expect that the number of items in mySafeCollection would always be the same as works and also none of the items in mySafeCollection would ever be null as I return a new instance of the result object for each call but it is not the case!!! Sometimes mySafeCollection is missing an item or one its elements is null meaning that GetResult has returned null. This does not make sense! result is created for every call to the GetResult method. I initially thought it would be because of the mySafeCollection collection where it used to be a list the issue is due to conrreuncy issues on the List.Add method but even switching to ConcurrentBag did not solve the issue. Any clue?

Comment: Why don't you use `.AsParallel().Select`?

Comment: Similar code as the one you posted should work. Could you post a small example that compiles, but doesn't work correctly?

Comment: How will .AsParallel().Select help? Isn't it same thing? Unfortunately, the code is much bigger to be shared

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that it's a race condition.  One of the overloads for Parallel.ForEach is

```
Action<TLocal> localFinally
```

If you use that action to catch the finally, it should, among other things, give you a chance to respond at a point that you can still do something about it.

Comment: It is a race condition but where could it be? Can you please explain what you mean by about code?